# Epsilon-delta definition of continuity in two dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity, absolute-continuity

Usually the continuity of multi-variate function is defined through something like ["$\delta$-disk."](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California%2C_Davis/UCD_Mat_21C%3A_Multivariate_Calculus/13%3A_Partial_Derivatives/13.2%3A_Limits_and_Continuity_in_Higher_Dimensions)

Can we define such continuity with the similar one-dimension definition? As follow:
$f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is continuous at $x$ iff $\forall\delta>0\exists\epsilon>0\forall y\in\mathbb R^2$ we have $|x-y|<\epsilon$ implies $|f(y)-f(x)|<\delta$.

If this definition works, then why do we need to complicate the problem?
If not, could you please provide a counterexample?

---

Similarly, there are many very complicated [generalization of absolute continuity in $\mathbb R^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87157/absolute-continuity-on-rn). Why don't people just use the same definition in $\mathbb R^n$ as if in $\mathbb R$ if that works? If it doesn't work in $\mathbb R^n$, then could you please bring a counterexample?

1d definition": $∀ε>0 ∃δ>0$ st $∑_j(y_j−x_j)<δ⟹∑_j|f(x_j)−f(y_j)|<ε$, where each $(x_j,y_j)$ is a subinterval of the domain of f. Can it be directly used in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Given that $\lvert x- y \rvert < \delta$ is a ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $x$ (or a so-called $\delta$-disk), how is the above definition different?

Comment: @GaryMoon I guess they are the same. Then why do we need to over-complicated it rather than saying that the definition is exactly same as the one in one dimensional case? I think math appreciates simplicity and concision.

Comment: I think that mentioning that to students is, in general, good and can aid in intuition/understanding. But, at the same time, you do, at some point, have to go through the process of constructing the machinery (e.g., replacing the absolute value with a higher-dimensional Euclidean norm) and actually showing that things work out like you say they will. Many things in math can be intuitive on the surface, yet take a good deal of effort to actually prove/verify. Take the Jordan curve theorem for example.

Comment: If there is a relation between the various dimensions you need to be careful in applying "disks" or "balls".

Comment: @GaryMoon Thanks! That makes sense. Any intuition for the absolute continuous case?

Comment: Is the $1d$ definition you have in mind $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta >0$ st $\sum_j (y_j-x_j) < \delta \implies \sum_j \lvert f(x_j) - f(y_j) \rvert < \varepsilon$, where each $(x_j,y_j)$ is a subinterval of the domain of $f$?

Comment: @GaryMoon Yes! I will update your notation into the question.